# ReactJS, add class to one button, not all (in .map render)

Tags: reactjs

I have this in the render:

```
    {categories.map((category) => {
      return (
        <>
          <Button
            key={category._id}
            id={category._id}
            className={dark ? classes.buttonDark : classes.button}
            onClick={() => handleSelectCategory(category)}
          >
            {category.name}
          </Button>
        </>
      )
    })}
```

The function `handleSelectCategory` is a setDark function, that toggles the `dark` value to true/false. But each rendered button is rendering with dark or not dark. How can I render with the buttonDark class only one button, the one that I click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the index that comes from categories `map` to discriminate which button is clicked. Of course, `dark` becames an array of bool. Something like:

```
const [dark, setDark] = useState(new Array(categories.length).fill(false));

const handleSelectCategory = (category, index) => {
   let result = [...dark];
   result[index] = !result[index];
   setDark(result);
}

...
{categories.map((category, index) => {
      return (
        <>
          <Button
            key={category._id}
            id={category._id}
            className={dark[index] ? classes.buttonDark : classes.button}
            onClick={() => handleSelectCategory(category, index)}
          >
            {category.name}
          </Button>
        </>
      )
    })}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap he function in the onclick after the arrow in an if statement that is dependent on some value of the maped objects. Like:

```
onClick={() => ((category.id == 2 )?(handleSelectCategory(category)):(console.log(category)}
```

EDIT:
Misunderstood the question, you must first render the dom, then manipulate the style based on the button you clicked.

```
<Button
        key={category._id}
        id={category._id}
        //remove the className or set it to the light color setting
        onClick={() => this.handleSelectCategory}
      >
```

handleSelectCategory should not pass the category. I.e. remove the () and just pass the element of button so

```
handleSelectCategory = () => {
    let id = e.target.id;
    document.getElementById(id).className = "dark";
}
```

Comment: But how I will know the _id before I click it? the _id comes from the object of the button that I click

Comment: The object that is being passed by the map contains the _id when it is mapped. Thus he _id is part of the element being constructed at the time the dom is written to the screen

Comment: React and DOM manipualtion are like cats and dogs... Don't do that, use hooks and state variables